# Dynamically update value of a key in Map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I currently have a function below to find the first nonrepeating letter. For example, for the string `carro`, that letter would be `c`; for the string `total`, that letter would be `o`.
I have the following code that works:

```
function findFirstNonrepeatedChar(str) {
  const store = {};
  const arr = str.split('');

  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(!store[item]) {
      store[item] = 1;
    } else {
      store[item] = store[item] + 1;
    }
  })
  
  for(let char in store) {
    if(store[char] === 1) return char;
  }
}
```

However, now I want to use a Map instead of just a plain object, and I'm having difficulty to update the frequency of the duplicate word like below:

```
function findFirstNonrepeatedChar(str) {
  const store = new Map();
  const arr = str.split('');

  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(!store.has(item)) {
      store.set(item, 1);
    } else {
      store[item]++;
    }
  })
  
  console.log(store, 'store')
  for(let char in store) {
    if(store[char] === 1) return char;
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: *for the string `total`, that letter would be `t`*, could you confirm this, because `t` occurs 2 time in `total`?

Comment: Sorry, that would be `o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things here:

- you `set` to save the key-value to store, use get to get the value by key

  ```
  store.set(item, (store.get(item) || 0) + 1);
  ```
- you iterate the key-value pairs of Map by `for..of`, not `for..in`

```js
function findFirstNonrepeatedChar(str) {
  const store = new Map();
  const arr = str.split("");

  arr.forEach((item) => {
    store.set(item, (store.get(item) || 0) + 1);
  });

  for (let [char, occurrences] of store) {
    if (occurrences === 1) {
      return char;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findFirstNonrepeatedChar("carro"));
console.log(findFirstNonrepeatedChar("total"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it using [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if you're interested in alternative solutions.

```js
const findFirstNonrepeatedChar = (str) => str.split('').find(
  (val) => str.match(new RegExp(val, 'g')).length === 1
);

console.log(findFirstNonrepeatedChar('total'));
console.log(findFirstNonrepeatedChar("carro"));
console.log(findFirstNonrepeatedChar("aabbcc"));
```